# PIC/non-PIC code errors when cross compiling

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling

This is totally outside my area of expertise, so forgive me if this seems rather elementary.  I've never really worked with C, so this is a bit new to me.  I've been tasked with cross-compiling [the ISC's DHCP implementation](http://www.isc.org/software/dhcp) into MIPS.  I have the compiler (mipsel-linux-gcc) and other assorted tools and it compiles fine but it fails when linking on every file:

> Bad value: failed to merge target
>   specific data of file ... linking PIC
>   files with non-PIC files

-fPIC and -fno-PIC changed nothing.  Is there a simple solution to this, or will I need to start rewriting chunks of this software?  Any input would be appreciated, I'm at a bit of a loss.

My configure line is as follows:

```
./configure CC=mipsel-linux-gcc CPP=mipsel-linux-cpp --host=mips --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something's wrong with libraries you're linking in. Make sure you have the standard library compiled for PIC, and that you link to it, not your system's.

Comment: To further clarify: PIC (Position Independent Code) is a property of  compiled code and has nothing to do with your source.

Comment: @Nathan: Gah, I missed that this was mips. I was thinking of [this](http://www.microchip.com/) PIC, but the answer is the same. Win!

Comment: Yes, what was happening is that a library was being compiled by gcc and the linker was trying to link x86 and MIPS code.